# URLs in iOS 17's New Speech Recognition API: prepareCustomLanguageModel vs Configuration URL

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, ios17

I'm working with the new speech recognition APIs in iOS 17 and have encountered some confusion regarding the use of URLs in [SFSpeechLanguageModel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechlanguagemodel).prepareCustomLanguageModel and the SFSpeechLanguageModel.Configuration.

In the [SFSpeechLanguageModel.Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechlanguagemodel/configuration) initializer, I provide a URL that points to a custom language model .bin file. However, there's also a URL parameter in the prepareCustomLanguageModel method. I'm unclear about the purpose of this second URL and how it differs from the one in the configuration.

To add to the confusion, the documentation for these new APIs is not fully fleshed out at this point. I've tried injecting both .bin files (for the custom language model and the one for prepareCustomLanguageModel) into the same URL, but the results haven't clarified their distinct roles.

In experiments I conducted, I checked the confidence level of recognized phrases from the same audio file with and without the custom language model .bin file. Surprisingly, the confidence levels remained the same in both scenarios, leading me to question if the custom model is being utilized correctly.

Has anyone else worked with these new APIs and can provide clarity on:

The distinct roles of the URLs in SFSpeechLanguageModel.Configuration and prepareCustomLanguageModel.
Why there might be no noticeable difference in confidence levels when using a custom language model.
Any insights or experiences with these new aspects of the iOS 17 speech recognition API would be greatly appreciated.